# Knockout observable subscribe doesn't recognize a change with date input in google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, knockout.js

Weird issue with Knockout.js whereas it won't recognize the date has been selected after reset, but only with the same date.

To replicate in my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V5JCq/ follow these steps:

1. pick any date
2. cllick reset
3. pick the same date you've picked in step 1

how? what? why?

code:

```
<input type="button" data-bind="click: resetDate" value="Reset">
<input data-bind="value : EstimatedDeliveryDate" type="date">
<span data-bind="html: selectedDate" />

var viewModel = {
    EstimatedDeliveryDate: ko.observable(),
    selectedDate: ko.observable()
};

viewModel.EstimatedDeliveryDate.subscribe(function (date) {
    viewModel.selectedDate("Date selected: " + date);
});

viewModel.resetDate = function () {
    viewModel.EstimatedDeliveryDate("");
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

**N.B.**: the issue is only applicable to **Google Chrome** v20+ which comes with built-in date picker for html5 date input control. Hence the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why, but it does not seem to be firing a `change` event in that scenario.  An easy fix is to specify that you want to listen to the `input` event as well using the `valueUpdate` additional binding like:

```
<input data-bind="value : EstimatedDeliveryDate, valueUpdate: 'input'" id="EstimatedDeliveryDate" name="EstimatedDeliveryDate" type="date"><span data-bind="html: selectedDate" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/geggJ/

Comment: OP should probably log a bug with Chrome.